# How to implement a complex decision in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, state-machine, finite-automata

**Context:**

We're writing logic for a signup component. If the user is not authenticated, the form should appear. If/when the user is authenticated it should redirect to one of several places. If there are unread messages, redirect to the first one. If there are no unread messages, redirect to the dashboard.

There is one more scenario we need to handle. When a new message arrives, a user can receive an email notification with a link to the signin form **plus** a query param with the ID of the specific message. Ex: `/signin?new_message=42`. In these situations, the signin form should appear if the user is not currently authenticated; if/when the user is authenticated, redirect to that specific message.

**My question:**

How can we implement this in an elegant and *extendible* way?

I *suspect* that a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) is the right tool for this job, but I am open to other approaches. I emphasized the word *extendible* because this is not code golf! I'm looking for a real-life solution that can scale gracefully to include additional business logic in the future.

NOTE: I don't actually care about javascript specifically, but StackOverflow best practices emphasize specificity and JS is the language I'm using. Therefore, an acceptable answer can use pseudo code as long it is conceptually compatible with javaScript. (Don't pseudo-code something that only works in Go)

Spoiler alert! Here's the WRONG answer:

```
if (authed && hasUnreadMessages && !clickFromEmail) {
  redirect = `/messages/${fistUnreadMessageId}`;
}
if (authed && !hasUnreadMessages && !clickFromEmail) {
  redirect = `/dashboard`
}
if (authed && clickFromEmail) {
  redirect = `/messages/${messageIdFromQueryString}`
}
...
```

^ A messy tangle of nested conditionals is the *problem* we're trying to solve.

**NOT my question**

This is a real-life example, but the main goal of my question is to learn about implementing complex decision logic. So I am not interested in architectural solutions that avoid this logic entirely. Ex: "Create different forms/endpoints to handle the different scenarios"

I'm also not interested in solutions that rely on a specific library. Ex: "You should just use ComplexSigninLibrary.js"

Product design or UX advice also misses the point of this question Ex: "It would be a better user experience to link directly from the email notifications to the new messages..."

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've described, it doesn't seem meaningful (or really possible) to determine if the request came from an e-mail.

All you need to do is:

1. Check if the user is authenticated

   - If the user is authenticated, check for a query-string and redirect based on thta query-string, if there is no query-string, redirect to the dashboard (you could just use a ternary operator for this)
   - If the user is not authenticated, display the login form

```js
if(authed) 
    redirect = messageIdFromQueryString ? `/messages/${messageIdFromQueryString}` : '/dashboard';
else
    redirect = '/login-form';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context and example given present the problem as "how do I make a decision based on the states of several boolean values" and for this problem there really is not a need or desire to complicate matters further than consecutive if statements, optionally using return to avoid nesting.

This is already clean and readable code, as well as probably the shortest and most efficient implementation of the conditions you've laid out:

```js
if (!authed) {
  return `/auth`;
}
if(clickFromEmail) {
  return `/messages/${messageIdFromQueryString}`;
}
if(hasUnreadMessages) {
  return `/messages/${fistUnreadMessageId}`;
}
return `/dashboard`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In an effort to keep the problem clear and minimal, I simplified the example a bit... the real example has a couple loading states to handle, too. For example, when the user hits the "page" the client has to make an API request to authenticate the user and we don't want to show the form while this is happening, but we also don't know if/where to redirect yet. I'll revise the question to capture this more clearly. The UI states don't map cleanly to individual booleans. Instead they depend on _combinations_ of the booleans. 